# Why CMYK prefered for printing purpose and not rgb color format

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As much as I know about Photoshop, we can change color mode (image->color mode-> cmyk). And cmyk is good for printing.So can I use .PSD file format for good quality printing purpose. Another question is that why CMYK is prefered for printing and rgb

Comment: What kind of printing are you doing?  Is it digital, home inkjet printing, offset lithography, screen printing, or what?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Control** over the process. Since the printer inherently works on a CMYK, this allows you to select all the colors the printer can produce, even the ones RGB can not produce.
2. **No surprises**! When you convert the RGB into CMYK, theres i something lost in the translation since the conversion is one to many. This allows you to have a opportunity to fix whatever problems might have come up. There is a infinite ways to do this conversions and you might prefer something that the computer did not do *automagically* (sic).
3. Many print houses *require* you to do this.

Not all print systems work on CMYK though so if your not doing this then theres no point in designing with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

CMYK colors on paper are color filters which take light off. This, the subtractive color formation, is just the opposite of the additive method, which is used in video screens. That is: The color is a sum of miniscule red, green and blue lamps.

Color dyes on paper are not ideal and definitely they take light off => Available color range is different, usually somehow limited, when compared to a good quality RGB screen.

Photoshop can simulate printable CMYK colors with mathematics. To see it you must have CMYK color mode and use the forthcoming printing color profile as your proof mode.

If you have color profiles well set in Photoshop and there's no breakage in color profile chain camera - photo preparation - photo usage in your work, you will get as consistent colors as your final printing method allows.

Usually conversion to CMYK reduces radically saturation because the richness of RGB images simply isn't printable. But you allways see what you will get and you can adjust your images for the available color range, if you have the color profiles set properly.

Learn color management basics for deeper explanations.

NOTE: Office printers often accept only RGB images altough they have CMYK inks. The conversion happens in the printer driver software and blocks you totally out of the process.